# How to import files from other coffeescript files

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am trying avoid duplicate import statements in my coffeescript files.

Say I need to import from these three files in all my *.coffee

```
#import "../node_modules/moment/moment.js"
#import "../testhelpers.js"
#import "../tuneup/tuneup.js"
```

How can I avoid code duplication? I tried

1. Creating a separate helper coffee file and importing it
2. Creating a separate helper JS file and importing it

But both didn't work.

This is not a web application, so size of javascript and unnecessary loading of JS isn't a concern.

Comment: Is this client-side or server-side?

Comment: Though this has npm modules this is UIAutomation through bwoken. Apple has its UI automation framework in javascript. Bwoken is a coffee script/console wrapper against it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using node.js, you use require:

```
moment = require "../node_modules/moment/moment.js"
testhelpers = require "../testhelpers.js"
tuneup = require "../tuneup/tuneup.js"
```

In addition, you will need to use the exports object in the files you are importing.

For example in moment.js:

```
exports.somefunc = (foo) -> console.log(foo)
```

Then, when you import:

```
moment = require "../node_modules/moment/moment.js"
moment.somefunc("hello world")
```

Anything not bound to `exports` will not be accessible when you call require.

Comment: But isn't this coffeescript? What does foo mean above>

Comment: That is coffeescript, I am just defining an example function just like the square function on the [coffeescript docs](http://coffeescript.org/). My function just prints out the value of an argument foo.